# How to avoid "apt-get" to stuck?

Tags: apt, scripts, wget

In some conditions like those :

- Slow internet connections
- Slow PPA or sources
- Wifi internet access or 3g internet access

apt-get may stuck during update, install, upgrade or dist-upgrade.... endlessly (up to you to force it to close)

When I say stuck : it downloads the files, start the download, slow down and wait at some point and simply stop to download but still waiting the end of the file.

From what I understand it seems to occurs when there is a lot of latency variations (so when a server is saturated or with a wifi/3g internet access)

This effect affects also with official repositories. so it's not a source.list thing.

How can we tell to apt-get :

1. to stop waiting endlessly
2. retry to download when there is a timeout or a packet loss during the download

I am looking for a solution that does not involve brute force methods such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or kill. I am looking for something more compatible with scripts (so no "human" intervention when the apt-get line has been launched).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` command (installed by the package by the same name) to run a command and kill it if it takes more than *N* seconds. I'd be careful about when to use it though. Killing apt-get during a package installation could mess things up, so I suggest only running the download part with timeout. Something like this bash function:

```
upgrade() {
    local retry=5 count=0

    # retry at most $retry times, waiting 1 minute between each try
    while true; do

        # Tell apt-get to only download packages for upgrade, and send 
        # signal 15 (SIGTERM) if it takes more than 10 minutes
        if timeout -15 600 apt-get --assume-yes --download-only upgrade; then
            break
        fi
        if (( count++ == retry )); then
            printf 'Upgrade failed\n' >&2
            return 1
        fi
        sleep 60
    done

    # At this point there should be no more packages to download, so 
    # install them.
    apt-get --assume-yes upgrade
}
```

See [How do I run a command, and have it abort (timeout) after N seconds?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068) for more.

Comment: Interesting ! So I assume that apt-get really don't have that functionality integrated ? Thank you for your solution, It will be useful for more than apt-get ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized update to @geirha's answer.

```
############ wrapper over apt-get to download files (retries if download fails) and then perform action.  
############ usage example:  aptgethelper install "nethogs rar -y -qq --force-yes"
function aptgethelper(){
local __cmd=$1
local __args=$2
local retry=10 count=0
set +x
    # retry at most $retry times, waiting 1 minute between each try
    while true; do

        # Tell apt-get to only download packages for upgrade, and send 
        # signal 15 (SIGTERM) if it takes more than 10 minutes
        if timeout --kill-after=60 60 apt-get -d $__cmd --assume-yes $__args; then
            break
        fi
        if (( count++ == retry )); then
            printf "apt-get download failed for $__cmd ,  $__args\n" >&2
            return 1
        fi
        sleep 60
    done

    # At this point there should be no more packages to download, so 
    # install them.
    apt-get $__cmd --assume-yes $__args
}
```